# Justification of LinkedList as a collection?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

The objects that are stored in LinkedList can be accessed by index, by using remove(int index) method.
And there is no method to remove data members by value?!

So how does this data structure justify being a LinkedList?

Comment: "And there is no method to remove data members by value?!" Can you please share the api you have looked into? It does provide, check the api [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Java implementation have remove method by value.

Comment: Why are you under the impression that the *purpose* of a LinkedList is to provide a `remove(value)` method? There are multiple reasons for having a Linked-List implementation, and that is definitely not one of them.

Comment: I'm guessing you're complaining about being unable to hold a reference to a given node in the list, which is a valid complaint, but a logical consequence of encapsulation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Maybe not a direct reference, but a `ListIterator` on a `LinkedList` does everything you'd want to do with a direct reference, while providing encapsulation.

Comment: @Subhrajyoti Majumder, so suppose i have a LinkedList L={11,12,13, 12, 12,14} and i want to remove 2nd "12" from L without using index, which method will you use?

Comment: @Andreas I am not saying that purpose of LL is to have a remove method, but i can access the members of LL by index or delete them by index which ideally should not be the case in a LL because a LL doesnt have index!

Comment: @NilayDhamecha To remove the 2nd "12" from the list, you'd first have to find it. For that, you'd call [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator()) on the list to get an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). When you find the value in question using that `Iterator`, you call [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) on the `Iterator`, which will do so directly, without index or value lookup.

Comment: Using `Iterator.remove()` is *O(1)* for *any* element of a `LinkedList`, unlike a remove from an `ArrayList`, which is *O(n)* because of the shifting of array values.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I found what I was looking for.      http://java-performance.info/linkedlist-performance/

Answer (score 0):

How to use LinkedList properly

The main property of LinkedList to remember – it offers only sequential access to its elements instead of random access of ArrayList. So, don’t try to adapt logic you’ve previously written with ArrayList in mind for the LinkedList – yes, they are both lists, but they are implemented too differently.

LinkedList is a sequential data structure. That’s why all linked list algorithms rely on iterators. In some cases, like remove(Object), iterator would be used implicitly, inside a library method, in other cases it must be used explicitly. For example, you have a LinkedList and you need to remove all Strings after a specified string which are 5 characters long. If specified string is not present, you must process the full buffer. If this example looks a little artificial, replace strings with messages with a timestamp and other properties, and it will become more real.

This could be a first approach to this problem – find position of required string using indexOf method and use this position as an argument for listIterator(int) method (and, of course, add 1 to this position to cater for ‘after a specified string’/’specified string not found’ cases.

```
public static void cleanStringListSlow( final LinkedList<String> lst, final String first )
{
    final int startPos = lst.indexOf( first ) + 1;
    final ListIterator<String> iter = lst.listIterator( startPos );
    while ( iter.hasNext() )
    {
        if ( iter.next().length() == 5 )
            iter.remove();
    }
}
```